# Create Custom pages in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

> If I want to create my own login page in Joomla, should I create it as
>   a component or a module?
>
> Does Joomla have the option for creating custom pages without using
>   component or module or plugin?

I have tried login page as a module but I don't know it is correct or not.

Comment: You can create your own pages but it does require a bit of work. Joomla is a CMS and therefore when you choose to you it, you should ensure that you actually require it. Should you have initially decided to create you own login page, then Joomla might have have been the answer for you

Answer (score 2):

Difference between module and component:

A component is the content part of a page. It can be selected when creating a new menu item (a new page). **It is assigned to the menu item**. If you look inside your template (index.php) you should see jdoc:include type="component" and that is where the component part gets loaded.

A module is just a part (block) of a page which can be on one page or many. If you look in your template you should see jdoc:include type="modules" name="..." and that is where your module gets loaded.

**In short if you want it to be the content of a page you want a component and if you want a block on any number of pages you want a module. (You may want both)**

BTW you can use either with workarounds like loading the module inside the article or loading the module instead of the component in the template if that menu item is active.

Comment: Login module and login component already exist in joomla - you dont need to create new ones but if thats what you're doing i suggest copying the default ones and modifying.